# Updated/new database information not showing up on tabbed forms in visual studio

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have been trying to solve this problem for several days now, I have found and tried bits and pieces of code but nothing seems to be working.

I have designed a form which uses a tab control to switch between different other "forms".

I have gotten code to read and write from a SQLCE server compact 3.5 (SDF) database, the problem I am having is when I add a new record or update an existing record on one "Tab" then switch to another tab which is supposed to display all records (I have tried textboxes as well as data grid view), the new records simply do not display. I have tried closing the connection and re-opening again, with the same result. I know the records are being added/updated because if I completely close the program and reopen it again, then the new records are shown.

CODE FOR ADDING NEW RECORDS:

```
Private Sub Button_AddToFavorites_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_AddToFavorites.Click
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim QueryString As String
    Dim connection As SqlCeConnection
    Dim command As SqlCeCommand
    Dim databaseArray(12) As String

    databaseArray(0) = Format(TextBox_DateTime.Value, "Short Date")
    databaseArray(1) = Replace(TextBox_Company.Text, "'", "")
    databaseArray(2) = ...

    connectionString = "Data Source=C:\...\Database_Favorites.sdf"
    QueryString = "INSERT INTO Favorites (Date, Company, Description, Shared, Split, Total, Type, Payee, CatName, FavoriteEntryTitle) VALUES ('" & databaseArray(1) & "','" & databaseArray(2)... & "')"
    connection = New SqlCeConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCeCommand(QueryString, connection)
    connection.Close()
    MsgBox("Data added to favorites")

End Sub
```

CODE FOR DISPLAYING RECORDS:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = Nothing
        Dim QueryString As String
        Dim connection As SqlCeConnection
        Dim command As SqlCeCommand
        Dim adapter As New SqlCeDataAdapter()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        QueryString = ""
        Textbox_EntryData.Text = ""

        connectionString = "Data Source=C:\...\Database_Favorites.sdf"
        QueryString = "SELECT * FROM [Favorites] ORDER BY Date DESC"

        connection = New SqlCeConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCeCommand(QueryString, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            adapter.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Textbox_EntryData.Text = Textbox_EntryData.Text & row(0) & ", " & row(1) & ", " & row(2).... etc
                Textbox_EntryData.Text = Textbox_EntryData.Text & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")
        End Try
End Sub
```

Code to display records does seem to work, however any updates or additions made while the form is loaded do not show within the textbox.